# AX 2012 retail statement posting involving retail kits

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

A change from origin with lot ID 025777372 to origin with lot ID 025777770 is not allowed because the values in field ItemInventDimId are not identical. I get this error when posting retail statements. From investigations this is because of retail kits in the sales transactions. The error happens in InventTransOriginKeyValueTransfer class method checkCanTransfer. I stepped through the code for a normal item and the retail kit and noticed that the normal item has the inventTransOrigin inventDimID for the statement record and the SO that is created during statement post set to ALLBLANK but the  retialkit has the  inventTransOrigin.inventDimID set to something else and the SO set to ALLBlank hence the error. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks